# Unpermitted parameters: image.Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I trying to add to my app 'carrierwave' gem.I create a class **image_uploader**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

and create a model **photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :post
end
```

and **photo.rb** has polymorphic association with **post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :post_attachments
  validates :title, :body, presence: true
  has_many :photos, as: :photoable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end
```

**post.rb** has a nested attributes from **photo.rb**

```
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, photo_attributes: [:image])
```

and this is partial **_form.html.haml** from **post.rb** model

```
= form_for [:admin, @post] do |f|
  = f.file_field :image
  = f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Title"
  = f.text_area :body, rows: 12, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Message"
  .pull-right
    = f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-success"
```

but when I create a post with image, shell show me an error

```
Unpermitted parameters: image
```

how fix it?

sorry for my bad English

***UPD***

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "photoable_id"
    t.string   "photoable_type"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

***SOLVED***

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `photos_attributes`.

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, photo_attributes: [:image])
                                                ^^
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this solution does not work.Сause of somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not using `fields_for` for the `image` attribute.

Instead of `= f.file_field :image`, you want:

```
= f.fields_for :photos do |photo_fields| %>
   = photo_fields.file_field :image
```

Then, change `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, photo_attributes: [:image])` to:

`params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, photos_attributes: [:image])`

Comment: thank you, I did like this http://pastie.org/9846945#, but an error 'Unpermitted parameters: photo'